# How to read and change other sections (not appsettings and connectionString ) in AppConfig file

Tags: c#, wcf

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBackend" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1005/Services/Backend/Backend.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IBackend" contract="Service.IBackend" name="BasicHttpBinding_IBackend" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

this code in my appconfig file and i want to read and edit (save) `address` string. so i have a code to edit and read , connectionString and other keys under AppSettings but i haven't found a way to access other sections. any suggestions for this incidence

i used this codes on connectionString

```
 public static string GetConnectionString(string key)
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        return config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString.ToString();
    }

public static void UpdateConnectionString(string key, string value)
    {
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        configFile.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString = value;
        configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }
```

Comment: those are WCF service client end points. let us know what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: WCF service is hosted. and my program has service reference to it.   when my program install to a pc I want to set that address by some interface  so I want to change that address by programmatically